# Loop and match strings between two different pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, match

I have two different dataframes df and df2, and i want to loop through each row of df in search of certain matches within specific rows in df2 and return a txt file for each match.

df=

```css
name Tec    Location
jhon js sr       nz
mark python ssr    us
alan java jr       mx
```

df2=

```css
company         job   Country    Index
company a js jr       uk     1
company b python ssr    us     2
company c java jr       mx     3
```

So far i've been doing the following:

```html
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for indexb, rowb in df2.iterrows():
        if str(row.Tec) in str(rowb.job) and str(row.Location) in rowb.Country:              
            print ('Match with ' + str(rowb.company))
            sys.stdout= open(r'path\to\file\%s.txt'%(row['name']+ str(rowb.Index),), 'w')
    else:
        pass
```

I keep getting text files with wrong matches or with the first row from df2 repeated within all output txt files.
I want to compare Tec against job and Location against country.
So for example, an output for this case would be:
mark 2.txt , where the file contains the text "Match with company b"

Any idea ?

Comment: What columns are you planning to match both dataframes on? Please add expected output for the sample input.

Comment: Done, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

Iterating rows is not the preferred way of working with Pandas DataFrames.

You might want to try joining df and df2. Then apply a filter to keep the rows you want to save into csv.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['jhon', 'js sr', 'nz'], ['mark', 'python ssr', 'us'], ['alan', 'java jr', 'mx']], columns=['name', 'Tec', 'Location'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['company a', 'js jr', 'uk'], ['company b', 'python ssr', 'us'], ['company c', 'java jr', 'mx']], columns=['company', 'job', 'Country'])
# Merge the two dataframes
df3 = df.merge(df2, how='right', left_on=['Tec', 'Location'], right_on=['job', 'Country'])
df3 = df3[df3['name'].notnull()]
df3['name'].to_csv('output.csv')
```